# Showing A Flash Message On Admin Entries Listing (Craft 3)

Tags: craft3

I've written a plugin that imports a CSV and creates entries from that for a client. I'm wanting to redirect them to the entries listing page after (i.e. /admin/entries/tvListings) and show a flash message saying "X TV listings imported.".

So this is a 2 parter:

1. How do you set flash data in Craft 3.
2. Is there a default flash key that'll show as soon as I land on the entries listing page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show a message

```
Craft::$app->getSession()->setNotice($message);
```

To show an error

```
Craft::$app->session->setError($message);
```

There is no "default" key that is always shown or something like that. You just use the function and set a message -> the next time the user visits *any* page the message is shown.

Comment: Hi Robin - that doesn't seem to work for me. I set the flash message then redirect away with '\Craft::$app->controller->redirect("/admin/entries/tvListings");' and I get no flash message.

Comment: I'm really sorry... I messed up the functions. Please see my update

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar. That worked perfectly. Thanks Robin.